# How to set delete on termination for boot volume in ec2 volume using ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

It appears to be easy to set delete on termination for new volumes attached to an ec2 instance, but how do I set that on the boot volume?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about this option to be set over root/boot volume during instance creation, if so here is the example code:

```
- name: Create EC2 Instance(s)
  ec2:
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    group: "{{ ec2_security_group_name }}"
    keypair: "{{ ec2_key_name }}"
    instance_type: "{{ ec2_instance_type }}"
    image: "{{ ami_find_result.results[0].ami_id }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnet_id }}"
    assign_public_ip: yes
    wait: True
    wait_timeout: 600
    user_data: |
              #!/bin/sh
              sudo apt-get install nginx -y
    instance_tags:
      Name: "{{ vpc_name }}-{{ SERVER_ROLE }}"
      Environment: "{{ ENVIRONMENT }}"
      Server_Role: "{{ SERVER_ROLE }}"
    volumes:
      - device_name: /dev/sda1
        volume_type: gp2
        volume_size: "{{ ec2_volume_size }}"
        delete_on_termination: yes
```

For details, please check this [link](https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-aws-roles/blob/master/roles/ec2instance/tasks/main.yml)
Hope that might help you